# Why am I not seeing most up to date version of records?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I run an ORM query to capture some records which I turn into a list of tuples:

```
matches = dal.session.query(
        today_table.TOUR,
        today_table.ROUND,
        today_table.ID1,
        today_table.ID2,
        today_table.RESULT,
    )
    return [match for match in matches]
```

I then have to run a Perl script to update the database from a third party. If I run the same query after the script has run then I get the same list of tuples even though the table in question has been updated.

Do I need to refresh SQLAlchemy in some way so it can see the latest set of records in the database?

Comment: Are you using MySQL? If so, you're likely using the default transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ. In order to read from a new snapshot you must end the current transaction.

Comment: Yes I am. How do I end the current transaction? Can I just do a ```dal.session.commit()```?

Comment: Yes, that'll do it, or rollback as well.

Comment: Great, thanks again!